# calling PowerShell script from batch file to connect remote machine is not working

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameter-passing, quoting

When I am running a PowerShell script normally it's working fine, issue is raising when calling the same script from batch file.

`Unt1.ps1` script:

```cs
$linux_app_user="ORXXXX\"+$args[0]
$pass_win=$args[1]
$path=$args[2]
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass_win -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
$linux_app_user, $pass
$Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXXXXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXXX -Credential $cred -ErrorAction 
Stop -ScriptBlock {
      param($path)
      Invoke-Expression $path
} -Arg $path
```

`cal.bat` script:

```cmd
@echo off

SET Server=slXXXXXXXX.XXX.XXXX.com
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy  RemoteSigned -File 
  C:\Users\chaj\Documents\String\Unt1.ps1 'XXXX' 'XXXX@321' 'C:\cal.bat'
```

Error:

```
[xxxxxx.xx.xxxxx.xxx] Connecting to remote server xxxxxx.xx.xxxxx.xxx failed
with the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect.
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\chafg\Documents\String\Unt1.ps1:7 char:1
+ $Result=Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxxxxx.xx.xxxxx.xxx -Credenti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (xxxxxx.xx.xxxxx.xxx) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : LogonFailure,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58764843/edit) to provide us with the actual correctly formatted content of `cal.bat`? _The only correct line is currently `@echo off`_

Comment: Both code snippets you posted are broken (incorrect line wrapping, missing double quote, ...). Please fix the code in your question. We cannot help you when the code you post doesn't allow us to reproduce the problem you're facing.

Comment: I modified the cal.bat code can you please verify the code and tell me solution for that problem

Comment: Your `cal.bat` content is still incorrect. These are non-critical: **`1.`** It doesn't use the recommended syntax for the `SET` commands, i.e. `SET "VarName=StringValue"`, **`2.`** There is a missing closing doublequote on your `CD` filepath. These are critical **`3.`** you have missed a line concatenation character or added an unwanted line break, and `cmd.exe` does not treat single quotes, **`'`**, in the same way as `powershell.exe` does for strings.

Comment: @Compo: While single quotes are definitely the wrong quotes to use, it occurred to me that `cmd.exe` is incidental in this scenario (except if you had unescaped `cmd.exe` metacharacters inside `'...'`): the issues is that with `-File`, PowerShell doesn't recognize single quotes as string delimiters either and considers them part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) **with the `-File` parameter, all arguments are used *verbatim* - except if enclosed in `"..."`** (double quotes): unlike when you use `-Command`, **`'...'` (single quotes) are *not* recognized as string *delimiters***.

Therefore, your command (simplified here):

> `powershell.exe -File C:\path\to\Unt1.ps1 'XXXX' 'XXXX@321' 'C:\cal.bat'`

causes the `Unt1.ps1` script to see the arguments *with the enclosing `'`*, which is not your intent; e.g., instead of `$args[0]` receiving `XXXX`, as intended, it receives `'XXXX'`, verbatim.

The **fix is to use `"..."` (double quotes)**:

```
powershell.exe -File C:\path\to\Unt1.ps1 "XXXX" "XXXX@321" "C:\cal.bat"
```

Alternatively, given that your specific sample arguments don't *require* quoting (though the real ones may):

```
powershell.exe -File C:\path\to\Unt1.ps1 XXXX XXXX@321 C:\cal.bat
```